# syntax, == operator when not in if statement.

Tags: swift

I came across this line of code

```
let shouldExpandWindow = self.itemsOffset + self.items.count == self.windowOffset + self.windowCount
```

I'm not used to seeing `==` outside of an if statement. I know that it's meant for comparisons. But how would it work in this case. Thank you

Comment: The result of the comparison (either `true` or `false`) is assigned to the variable `shouldExpandWindow` which has the type `Bool`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you

Comment: `if` works with any `Bool`. `==` happens to return a `Bool`, and you'll often see it used as an `if` statement's predicate. But you can use any other `Bool` value, such as `if true { /* ... */ }`, `if someBoolFunction() { /* ... */ }`, `if x < 5 { /* ... */ }`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is a function that takes two values of the same type (such as `Int`) and returns a `Bool`.  For example, if you are comparing two `Int`s, the function signature is:

```
func ==(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Bool
```

The result of the comparison is then assigned to `shouldExpandWindow` which Swift infers to have the type `Bool`.

You can find this out for yourself by <kbd>option</kbd>-clicking on `==`:

[image]